# Beginner; GUI not appearing?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to java and coding. I tried searching this problem but could not find a solution.

I was given this code as an example on paper. I tried to recreate it in Eclipse but when I run the code, nothing happens (no gui popup or anything like that). It wouldn't work in jGrasp either. Anyone know what is wrong?

Thanks

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;

import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.media.AudioClip;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;

public class AudioShuffle extends Application {
    private AudioClip audio1;
    private AudioClip audio2;
    private AudioClip audio3;
    private AudioClip audio4;
    private Button play, stop, shuffle;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        String clipURL = "http://www.music.helsinki.fi/tmt/opetus/uusmedia/esim/a2002011001-e02-16kHz.wav";
        audio1 = new AudioClip(clipURL);
        play=new Button("PLAY");
        play.setStyle("-fx-font:20 Arial");
        stop=new Button("STOP");
        stop.setStyle("-fx-font:20 Arial");

        play.setOnAction(this::processButtonPress);
        stop.setOnAction(this::processButtonPress);

        FlowPane pane = new FlowPane(play, stop);
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        pane.setHgap(20);
        pane.setStyle("=fx=background=color: cyan");

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300,100);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Audio Playlist");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void processButtonPress(ActionEvent event){
        if(event.getSource()==play){
            audio1.play();
        }
        else if(event.getSource()==stop){
            audio1.stop();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
    }
}
```

Comment: I would HIGHLY recommend that you start by having a look at [Getting started with JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm) which has a runnable example.  I would compare the example with your code and see where the differences are

Comment: I would also suggest having a look at [A closer look at the "Hello World!" application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/) - in particular, have a look at the section on *"The `main` method"*

Comment: Your `main` method does nothing.

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering about that.. The paper copy of the main method has nothing. I tried putting "Application.launch(args);" there and it worked. Thanks for the help.